# Не восстанавливаются бэкапы ящика Zimbra

Tags: резервное-копирование, zimbra

Приблизительно 2 недели назад прекратили восстанавливаться из бэкапа ящика зимбры почта пользователей в уже существующий почтовый ящик.
Бэкап делал

```
zmmailbox -z -m e@mail.mail -t 0 getRestURL "//?fmt=tgz" > /backup/backup.tgz
```

Восстанавливал

```
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmmailbox -z -m e@mail1.mail -t 0 postRestURL "//?fmt=tgz&resolve=modify" backup.tgz
```

Раньше письма добавлялись к тем, которые уже есть ящике на другом сервере, сейчас все пусто. В чистый ящик, который только создан на втором сервере письма восстанавливаются, но при заливке следующего бэкапа опять писем не появляется.

Comment: А Вы не пробовали без -t? А если попробовать?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на этот вопрос оказался прост - по непонятной причине при копировании архив бился и не открывался. Задача решалась сменой сетевых настроек и, как второе решение - переделал обмен через ftp. Заодно и копия есть.